# Is there a way to hide certain files on Github from non-collaborators?

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook

I'm currently making a Github repository where I'll have Jupyter Notebooks to create PDFs for anyone to access. However, I don't want non-collaborators to be able to access the Jupyter Notebooks. Is it possible to hide the notebooks from those who are not collaborators, but keep them accessible to me? I currently have the Jupyter Notebooks in .gitignore, but this makes it difficult to work across computers, as they are no longer pushed to the repository. Is there any way to do this, or should I just create a private repository for the notebooks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a private repository for these that's separate from the main repository.

In general, a person with access to clone or fetch from a Git repository can read any object in that repository.  From `gitnamespaces(7)`:

> The fetch and push protocols are not designed to prevent one side from stealing data from the other repository that was not intended to be shared. If you have private data that you need to protect from a malicious peer, your best option is to store it in another repository. This applies to both clients and servers.

The manual page then goes on to describe various attacks that can occur to allow a user to exfiltrate data from the repository by knowing only some of the data.

Note that the repository you create for this private data should not be a fork of the main repository because GitHub shares objects across forks and it would be possible for an attacker to perform the same attack on a fork.